# RN4678 Bluetooth doesn't respond

Tags: bluetooth

I am facing very basic level issue with RN4678. I purchased a module from https://www.mikroe.com/rn4678-click

I want to simply communicate with it through serial port.  To do that I connected it to PC by usb to TTL. Whatever I send, I don't get any response from module.  Then parallely I paired it with mobile phone and on successful connection, from  Android app terminal I tried the same and nothing happened.  If I send something from PC, I get it on mobile but reverse doesn't work.    And the main issue is Module doesn't respond at all.   I tried 3modules as well.
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your USB to TTL is implementing flow control on the UART. An option is to delete the CTS/RST in RN configuration and try two wire UART to eliminate CTS/RTS option